# split String If get any capital letters

Tags: java, regex

My String:
`BByTTheWay` .I want to split the string `as B By T The Way BByTheWay` .That means I want to split string if I get any capital letters and last put the main string as it is. As far I tried in java:

```
public String breakWord(String fileAsString) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String allWord = "";
    String allmethod = "";
    String[] splitString = fileAsString.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        String k = splitString[i].replaceAll("([A-Z])(?![A-Z])", " $1").trim();
        allWord = k.concat(" " + splitString[i]);
        allWord = Arrays.stream(allWord.split("\\s+")).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        allmethod = allmethod + " " + allWord;
        //  System.out.print(allmethod);
    }
    return allmethod;

}
```

It givs me the output: `B ByT The Way BByTTheWay`   . I think stackoverflow community help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this code:

**Code 1**

```
String s = "BByTTheWay";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}*");

String out = p.matcher(s)
     .results()
     .map(MatchResult::group)
     .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
     + " " + s;

//=> "B By T The Way BByTTheWay"
```

RegEx `\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}*` matches any unicode upper case letter followed by 0 or more lowercase letters.

<kbd>[CODE DEMO](https://ideone.com/T3wAy1)</kbd>

---

Or use `String.split` using same regex and join it back later:

**Code 2**

```
String out = Arrays.stream(s.split("(?=\\p{Lu})"))
    
.collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) + " " + s;
//=> "B By T The Way BByTTheWay"
```

Comment: here .results() shows me **cannot find symbol** ..I am using java version "1.8.0_111" -

Comment: ok that is due to version incompatibility, can you try my `Code 2`.

Comment: FYI, both of your solutions work successfully with diacriticals. `String s = "ÀLaCarte";`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```java
String s = "BByTTheWay";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
String r = "";
while (m.find()) {
    r = r + m.group(0) + " ";
}
System.out.println(r + s);
```

See [Java proof](https://ideone.com/bQrW0J).

**Results**: `B By T The Way BByTTheWay`

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]*                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer .The code you provide that's so easy to understand

Comment: Fails with diacriticals. `String s = "ÀLaCarte";`

Comment: @BasilBourque No fail at all, `BByTTheWay` has no diacriticals. The expression is fully in line with OP code attempt, without guesswork. Sanzida, please kindly let know if diacritcials are an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per requirements, you can write in this way [checking if a character is an alphabet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/charintro.html) or not:

```
char[] chars = fileAsString.toCharArray();
StringBuilder fragment = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : chars) {
    if (Character.isLetter(ch) && Character.isUpperCase(ch)) { // it works as internationalized check
        fragment.append(" ");
    }
    fragment.append(ch);
}
String.join(" ", fragment).concat(" " + fileAsString).trim(); // B By T The Way BByTTheWay
```